# Rollback update

Tags: updates

Two days ago I accepted suggested updates, after which my laptop's touchpad stopped working and my shortcut keys no longer apply (i.e. <kbd>F12</kbd> to open/close yakuake).

Looking at the apt log I notice a ton of packages were updated or removed.

Is there a way to roll back, ideally "undo" this whole update?

[image: snippet]

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text; I can't copy/paste from a picture, plus text is easier to read.  If you're using a Synaptics s3203 touchpad, it's probably related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798  (though you didn't give release details; but matches 16.04 with HWE or 18.04 without HWE).  Roll-back is possible for some file-systems (but no details are provided of what you have).

Comment: The best method is doing a full system backup (or cloning) before applying updates. This is especially true during version upgrades when things are more likely to break than during regular daily updates.

Comment: After you get this mess cleaned up, take a look at **Timeshift**. It's designed exactly for the purpose of rolling back to a previously working system.